# Show that the max and min of two simple functions are simple

Tags: real-analysis

I understand how to prove  the sum and product of two simple functions are simple functions but I’m stuck trying to show that max and min of two simple functions are simple.

Here are my thoughts so far:

**Theorem: Let f and g be two functions defined on I. Then max(f,g)+min(f,g)=f+g**

Given that f+g are simple functions, can I use this theorem to prove max and min of two simple functions are simple?

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\max(f,g) =(f+g+|f-g|)/2$ and $\min(f,g) =(f+g-|f-g|)/2.$ Then you only need to show that the sum (difference) of two simple functions is simple, a scalar multiple of a simple function is simple, and then that the absolute value of simple functions is simple. Then the result follows.